# Django Crispy Forms - Checkbox not being displayed

Tags: django, django-templates, bootstrap-4, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to add a boolean field on my form and render it with crispy forms tags. And everything is showed except for the checkbox.

My project works with django 2.1, python 3.6 and Bootstrap-4. My version of Django Crispy Forms is: 1.7.2

The field is `investment`.

**Model field not working:**

`investment = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Want to accept Investments?')`

**My form:**

```
class CreateProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('name', 'short_description', 'category', 'investment')
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'enter the project name here...'}),
            'short_description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': '2', 'maxlength': '135', 'class': 'textarea-limited',
                                                        'placeholder': 'enter a short description of your project limited to 135 characters'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # first call parent's constructor
        super(CreateProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # there's a `fields` property now
        self.fields['investment'].required = True
        self.fields['investment'].widget = forms.CheckboxInput()
        self.fields['name'].widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'enter the project name here...'})
        self.fields['short_description'].widget = forms.Textarea(
            attrs={'rows': '2',
                   'maxlength': '135',
                   'class': 'textarea-limited',
                   'placeholder': 'enter a short description of your project limited to 135 characters'})
        # evade all labels and help text to appear when using "as_crispy_tag"
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
        self.helper._help_text_inline = True
```

**My View:**

```
class ProjectCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin, generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'webplatform/project_create_form.html'
    model = Project
    form_class = CreateProjectForm
    success_message = 'Project created! Now try to add all the details and then publish it!'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('project-edit-general', args=(self.object.id,))

    # Set field as current user
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.start_date = timezone.now()
        form.instance.history_change_reason = 'Project Created'
        return super(ProjectCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

*And for the template I tried two methods, but none of them worked:*

**My template 01:**

This is the method I want to use at the end. Displaying each fiend individually so I can make the layout directly on the template.

```
...
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
...
<form id="my_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                            <h6>Name
                                <span class="icon-danger">*</span>
                            </h6>
                            {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}

                            <h6>Categories
                                <span class="icon-danger">*</span>
                            </h6>
                            {{ form.category|as_crispy_field }}

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                            <h6>Short Description
                                <span class="icon-danger">*</span>
                            </h6>
                            {{ form.short_description|as_crispy_field }}
                            <h5>
                                <small>
                                    <span id="textarea-limited-message" class="pull-right">135 characters left</span>
                                </small>
                            </h5>
                            <h6>Investment
                                <span class="icon-danger">*</span>
                            </h6>
                            {{ form.investment|as_crispy_field }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row buttons-row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block btn-round">Create</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

**My template 02:**

This one is using directly the `{{ form|crispy }}` to show all the elements automatically.

```
...
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
...
<form id="my_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                    <div class="row buttons-row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block btn-round">Create</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I checked the rendered HTML and I found where the problem seems to be, but I don't know how to solve it:

Crispy forms create an element adding the corresponding divs and other necessary elements, like for example on the name input:

```
<div id="div_id_name" class="form-group"> 
        <label for="id_name" class="col-form-label  requiredField">Name
            <span class="asteriskField">*</span> 
        </label> 
    <div class=""> 
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="enter the project name here..." class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_name"> 
            <small id="hint_id_name" class="form-text text-muted">Add a title to your project.</small> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

But for the checkbox creates the following structure:

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    <div id="div_id_investment" class="form-check"> 
        <label for="id_investment" class="form-check-label requiredField"> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="investment" class="checkboxinput form-check-input" required="" id="id_investment">
                    Investment
                <span class="asteriskField">*</span> 
        </label> 
        <small id="hint_id_investment" class="form-text text-muted">Want to accept Investments?</small> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

As you can see, the `div` with the `id` is inside another `div`. Well, so if I delete the class of this extra `div` (`form-group`) and change the class of the `div` with `id`: `form-check` for `form-group`, the checkbox appears and is fully functional.

So my idea is try to change the template that crispy forms created for the checkbox, But I don't know how to do that. Also, if there is another better option, I'm open to them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change self.fields['investment'].required = False, 'cause it seems that because the field is not specified as optional Django ignores it.

Comment: It does not work. Everything is equal as my first try. I also tried to delete all widgets and helpers and happens the same everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Their is an open issue in django-crispy-forms github see : https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/issues/787

According to this the issue is the way bootsrap handle this form element in the last version.
Here is a js hack to make it work :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ":checkbox" ).each(function( index ) {
        $(this).prependTo($("#div_" + $(this).attr('id')))
    });
});
```

Comment: I added this JS to my project but didn't work. It stays the same. I tried to add this JS into the header and also at the end of the body, but nothing.

Comment: Did you import jquery like this:

    `<head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">       </script>
    </head>`

Comment: Yes, tried at the header and at the end of the body too.

Answer (score 0):

I could make a half hack for this by the element I needed by using the following JS:

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
        $('#div_id_investment').addClass('form-group').removeClass('form-check');
});
```

But this just let the user see and interact with the checkbox, it does not solve that if the field is required and you don't click it, the error message it doesn't appear.

If anyone have an improved JS to make this to all checkboxes and solve the problem with the error message, I'll appreciate it.

note: I'm not marking this as a valid answer for the question because the bug still there and this 'hack' doesn't solve all the problems.